# Is it possible to have a REST API server start in a Chrome extension?

Tags: rest, google-chrome-extension

Suppose that I want to open Chrome on my PC and then enable an extension, and just leave it idle in the background. Would it be possible to have the extension spin up a REST API server that can then be consumed by, say, some Raspberry Pis (assuming the PC's firewall allows for it, of course)?

Comment: No, but you can write a separate utility and launch it from the extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: I haven't written a chrome extension before, but this might be helpful for you: https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome

Comment: @wOxxOm This has some neat flexibility to it. I think I'll do that.

Comment: @nthnchu, that's a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), not an extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh, okay. I didn't know they were different.